# vmware player turns off when I try to power on a VM

Tags: vmware-player

after having upgraded from lubuntu 16.04 to ubuntu 18.04 (which I installed on a new SSD), VMware player will not start my virtual machines. On klicking "power on", it simply vanishes. After that, a report of an ubuntu system error is sent. What can be the reason?

Comment: Post the error ....

Comment: Error details contain "general protection fault". Details wont copy via copy & paste. - Where do I find the error details as a file?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, when I click on power on button vmplayer would close.

Solution: Make sure virtualization is enable in your BIOS.